# Two Dimensional Value Function Iteration: Vectorizing in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, vectorization

I'd like to solve a two dimensional dynamic programming problem. I use value function iteration over some symmetric meshgrid on `TxT`. Right know I'm looping over every state `(t_i,t_j)` in `TxT` and find the optimal control `(I_i,I_j)`. However the procedure is rather time consuming. I'd like get rid of the for loop. Is it possible to define `objective` on a `TxT` grid, supply an initial matrix `I0` and find all `(I_i,I_j)`   within one step.

```
[...]

% vfi loop
while(iterate < max_iter & error > error_tol)
    w_fit = fit([t1, t2], w, 'poly23');
    % maximizing objective function for every possible state
    for i = 1:length(w)
        objective = @(I) -(h*1/6*((t1(i) + t2(i))/(2*c)...
            - (a*(t1(i).^2 + t2(i).^2) + b*(I(1).^2 + I(2).^2)))...
            +(1-r*h)*w_fit(t1(i) + h*(I(1) - d*t1(i)), t2(i) + h*(I(2) - d*t2(i))));
        I_star =fminsearch(objective,[I1_0(i), I2_0(i)]);
        pi_1(i) = I_star(1);
        pi_2(i) = I_star(2);
        Tw(i) = -objective(I_star);
    end
    iterate = iterate + 1
    error = max(abs(Tw - w))
    w = Tw;
    I1_0 = pi_1;
    I2_0 = pi_2;
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that the "vectorization" of the loop will bring you much advantage (and I don't see how you'd do such a vectorization). The most computing intensive part will be `fminsearch`, which will call multiple times the anonymous function stored in `objective`. So, the goal is to optimize the execution of *that* function. The best trick: compute only once the terms and factors that don't depend on the anonymous function's input (outside the function definition), and use the precomputed values inside the anon function definition.

Other optimizations may be done by tweaking `fminsearch` itself: relax the tolerances, decrease the configured number of iterations or function evaluation, suppress the diagnostic messages and plots. See the help here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html

Comment: Yes, my idea is to get rid of using  `fminsearch`. In these notes http://paulklein.ca/newsite/teaching/912notesmacro315.pdf it is described for an specific example. However, I'm not able to translate it for my problem at hand.